# Undefined property: App\Controllers\Admin::$user

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-4

I want to Login whenever I click the submit button, I get all information on username and password to log in and can get in into the dashboard. can somebody help me?

but I got an error like this
`Undefined property: App\Controllers\Admin::$user`

this is my code:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new UserModel();
        $this->sponsor = new SponsorModel();
        $this->auditorium = new auditoriumModel();
    }
public function index()
    {
        $user = $this->user->findAll();
        $audVid = $this->auditorium->findAll();
        $sponsorData = $this->sponsor->findAll();
        $data = [
            'user' => $user,
            'sponsorData' => $sponsorData,
            'audvid' => $audVid
        ];
        // dd($sponsorData);
        echo view('templates/header');
        echo view('login', $data);
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function doLogin()
    {
        $email
            = $this->request->getVar('email');
        $password =
            $this->request->getVar('password');
        $userData = $this->user->where('email', $email)
            ->where('password', $password)
            ->findAll();
        if ($userData == null) {
            return redirect()->to('/admin');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['logonUser'] = 'aktif';
            return redirect()->to('/adminDashboard', $userData);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my login view

```
<form id="login-form" class="form" action="/admin/doLogin" method="post">
    <h3 class="text-center text-info">Login Admin</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="text-info">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <labezl for="remember-me" class="text-info"><span>Remember me</span> <span><input id="remember-me" name="remember-me" type="checkbox"></span></labezl><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="submit" href="/adminDashboard">
    </div>
    <div id="register-link" class="text-right">
        <a href="#" class="text-info">Register here</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

can somebody help me to solve my code?
thanks

Comment: this is my view login

Comment: Which line does the error occur?

Comment: Please post the entire controller code, and tell us the line where the error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $userData = $this->user->where('email', $email)
        ->where('password', $password)
        ->findAll();
```

findAll() will get you an array of rows that applies to your criteria. In your case will try to find all users where email and password are correct, but it will still return you an array of them, not just one. You need to be using find() instead.